# ASP.NET: two ways to access global resource programmatically

Tags: asp.net, resource-files

I know that I can set a Label's text by using the following syntax.

```
lblMessage.Text = (string)GetGlobalResourceObject("resxFile", "message");
```

What are the benefits and drawbacks associated with using the below syntax?

```
lblMessage.Text = Resources.resxFile.message;
```

The second method will not work for local resource files. Is there a different syntax for local resource files?

Comment: Notice that the second way of accessing a resource file only works if you don't plan to localize and thus name it "Resources.TextResources.resx" instead of "Resources.TextResources.en.resx"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second way looks better because it is strongly-typed.  If you changed the resource file name or the resource value name then you would get a compile error.  If you needed to dynamically get a resource, then you would have to do it the first way, else use a switch statement or something similar.

If you are using asp.net 2.0 or higher there is actually a 3rd way to set a label by using markup only:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:resxFile,message %>" />
```

Kinda related to localization: http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/aspnet/doc/localization/localization.aspx